# Concatenate CheckboxList values and Insert Into table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, checkboxlist

Due to my limited knowledge in ASP.Net I am stuck in the following problem, I have four check boxes, I would like to insert the value of the checkboxes into a table. The value should be: plan1 if the first checkbox is selected, plan1plan2 if the both plan1 and plan2 are selected, plan1plan2plan3 if plan1, plan2, plan3 are selected and so on.

This is my asp.net code:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="870px" Height="139px">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Plan1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Plan2" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Plan3" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Plan4" Value="4" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

This is my C# code:

```
const string query = "INSERT INTO deductiblePlan (planName) VALUES (@planName)";

using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    foreach (var item in CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected))
    {
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@planName", item.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The above method is inserting each selected value individually, for example if I select two plans it will insert two records which is not what I want, I want one record with plan1plan2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just concatenate them together in the foreach and then do one insert.

```
const string query = "INSERT INTO deductiblePlan (planName) VALUES (@planName)";

using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    string planName ="";
    foreach (var item in CheckBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected))
    {
       planName =planName+item.Text
    }
    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@planName",planName );
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```